# C++ convert wwn string to data type recognized as hex

Tags: c++

A project I am working on already has the wwn of a iscsi device stored as a std::string less the colons.  I have to grab a subset of the string and XOR them as if they were bytes with another set of bytes for a scsi command security code.  Which data type should I be converting the characters too so that the XOR treats them as hex bytes.  The numbers are already exactly what I need but the compiler is going to interpret them as ASCII.  I just need a way to tell the compiler these are already hex bytes.

The string is 601ad142 so i need to convert it too [0x60, 0x1a, 0xd1, 0x42] so I can xor each byte with [0x57, 0x68, 0x6f, 0x61]

If I can convert the wwn string: `600601601ad14200b9265b5b274efb84` (already provided in the existingcode) to a uinit64_t I can work with that too but:

```
std::string wwid(path.wwid);
wwid.erase(std::remove(wwid.begin(), wwid.end(), ':'), wwid.end());//remove colons
uint64_t wwn = wwid
std::istringstream strWwid(wwid);
strWwid >> wwn;
```

return `0x23cc7401`

**UPDATE**: I found a working solution.

```
std::string wwid(path.wwid);
wwid.erase(std::remove(wwid.begin(), wwid.end(), ':'), wwid.end());
char wwnBytes[8];
strncpy( wwnBytes, wwid.c_str() + 6, 8); // get chars for bytes 4 -7
std::string bytes = wwnBytes;
std::stringstream ss;
unsigned int secBytes;
ss << std::hex << bytes;
ss >> secBytes;
```

Comment: Can you give an example of what the string(s) look like and what you want to have at the end?

Answer (score 0):

Hexadecimal is a textual representation – `{0x60, 0x1a, 0xd1, 0x42}` is the same as `{96, 26, 209, 66}`.

Your string contains the (ASCII) representation of those characters (`'6'`, `'0'`, et c) and you need to convert those to the numbers they represent.

For one character, something like

```
// Assumes that c is an ASCII-encoded hexadecimal digit.
// TODO: Add input validation.
unsigned int from_hex(char c)
{
    return (c <= '0' && c <= '9') 
          ? c - '0'
          : 10 + std::toupper(c) - 'A';
}
```

and to convert two digits to a byte value, you could use

```
unsigned int from_hex(char hi_bits, char lo_bits)
{
    return from_hex(hi_bits) * 16 + from_hex(lo_bits);
}
```

then `from_hex('6', 'f')` will produce one hundred and eleven, which is written 6f in hexadecimal.

Comment: The WWN of the device is already in hex and separating each byte by colons but code has stored it as a string I just need away to tell the compiler these values are hex not ascii

Comment: To be more clear your are going in the wrong direction.  I need to go from string to hex but in this case I don't need conversion I just need to have get the code to treat the string as hex by some means of changing the data type.

Comment: @user1370416 No, you need to go from "hex string" to integers. The string really is the ASCII representation of the digits, and you can't just interpret them as a different type.

Comment: I see your point.  I am very new to C++, like two months.  I'll give your example a try

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this using std::stringstream:

```
std::string wwid(path.wwid);
wwid.erase(std::remove(wwid.begin(), wwid.end(), ':'), wwid.end());
char wwnBytes[8];
strncpy( wwnBytes, wwid.c_str() + 6, 8); // get chars for bytes needed
std::string bytes = wwnBytes;
std::stringstream ss;
unsigned int secBytes;
ss << std::hex << bytes;
ss >> secBytes; // bytes 4-7 in hex
```

Resulting unsigned int yields the expected hex values